# How to pip install private repository that has a private submodule in docker build?

Tags: docker, pip, git-submodules

I am building a project which requires some dependencies on private python repositories. This repo has inside a submodule which also points out to a private repo. I can fetch it on my machine using an ssh key which is not convenient inside a container.

In my dockerfile, I am blocking on this step:

```
RUN pip3 install wheel \
  && pip3 wheel git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/owner/repo.git@master \
--wheel-dir=/svc/wheels
```

It can fetch repo without problem but cannot handle the submodule. I guess pip resolves the URL and doesn't pass the token initially transferred.

I don't really know how to workaround the issue. I could have the folder locally and copy it, or setup a private pip repo I'd access during build time (if it's possible), or use ssh keys inside the container (sounds like a terrible approach to me).

Is there any "standard way to do it" ? If not what would you suggest?

EDIT1: this seems like a git issue as `git clone --recursive` doesn't work neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing `${GITHUB_TOKEN)` on the command line, you should be able to configure that into a `.netrc` file as described e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github).

Your `Dockerfile` would include something like:

```
RUN echo machine github.com login ${GITHUB_TOKEN} > ~/.netrc
RUN pip3 install wheel \
  && pip3 wheel git+https://github.com/owner/repo.git@master \
--wheel-dir=/svc/wheels
```

Comment: I didn't know about this feature, thanks for the advice. nevertheless, it still gives the same result with a private submodule inside

Comment: Odd, it works just fine my test, although I'm using `git` directly rather than `pip` because I have access to a limited number of private github repositories and none of them are hosting a Python module.  Did the `git clone` for the master repository succeed?

Comment: I just found out the issue in my submodule declaration. It was set up using ssh. `url = git@github.com:` instead `url = https://github.com/`.

Thanks for spending time and effort testing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command in the `dockerfile`, before `RUN pip install ...`

```
RUN git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github".insteadOf https://github
```

This will replace the occurrences of `https://github` with `https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github`, even at a submodule level when `git` command is executed.

Note: In the parent repository, the submodule url (defined in `.gitmodules`) should be set to `https://github` instead of `git@github`.